# Layer visibility using maxscale minscale not working

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, layers, visibility

I'm using OpenLayers and GeoServer. I have a series of layers that have a scale parameter like: 1:50000-1:25000 where 50000 is the max scale while 25000 is the min scale.

I have a map like in this example:

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map(
{
        allOverlays: false,
        projection: "EPSG:32632",
        maxExtent: bounds,
        scales:[500000,350000,250000,100000,25000,20000,15000,10000,5000],        
        units: 'm'
});
```

And I have this layer WMS:

```
var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("layer1",wms_address,
        {
            layers:"ws:layer1",
            transparent:true                            
        },
        {
        maxScale:50000,
        minScale:25000
    });
```

and I would expect that the layer within that scale it doesn't show up in the map. I need this kind of behaviour. However if I set the scale 1:25000, the layer is present inside the map (I saw it with Firebug) but it is not showed up in the map!

I also tried with max and min Resolution but nothing, the layer is in the map but I cannot see it.

What I'm doing wrong?

Please help me, I looked everywhere in every forum I don't know how to solve this problem!

Comment: No one can help me please? I'm would like to know if I'm doing some errors in my code....Thanks

Comment: does your map show up with out the scale settings?

Comment: @iant The map does show up with the scale settings, but the layer does not show up if I put the max or min Scale values options of the layer.If I don't set min max Scale for the layer, I see the layer on the map. My problem is that I need to set scale values for each layer that I add on the map. So what am I doing wrong? Please help me...

Comment: it sounds as if your scale settings are wrong - try setting just min or max and working from there

Comment: I finally solved my problem some time ago by using the arrey "resolution" instead of setting maxScale or minScale values. It seems that OpenLayer does not recognize the layer visibility through these params. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Visit [maxScale or minScale don't work in vector (from WFS) layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61918/maxscale-or-minscale-dont-working-in-vector-from-wfs-layer) for a similiar question.

```
maxScale:50000,
minScale:25000
```

should be changed to:

```
maxScale: 1/25000,
minScale: 1/50000
```