# maxScale or minScale don't work in vector (from WFS) layer

Tags: openlayers-2, wfs, scale-factor

```
var options = 
    {
        projection: "EPSG:900913",
        displayProjection: "EPSG:4326",
        units: 'm'
    };
    map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', options);    

ilceSinir = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("İlçe Sınırı",
    {
        minScale: 150000,
        strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()], 
        projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS(
        {
            version: "1.1.0",
            url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs",
            featurePrefix: 'topp',
            featureType: "g_ilce_siniri", 
            featureNS: "http://www.openplans.org/topp",
            geometryName: "bounds" 
        })
    });
```

Scale isn't working, layer is visible at every zoom.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE forum. Which software you are using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about this:

```
var options = 
    {
        scales: [50000, 100000, 150000],
        minScale: 150000,
        projection: "EPSG:900913",
        displayProjection: "EPSG:4326",
        units: 'm'
    };
    map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', options);

ilceSinir = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("İlçe Sınırı",
    {
        strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()], 
        projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS(
        {
            version: "1.1.0",
            url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs",
            featurePrefix: 'topp',
            featureType: "g_ilce_siniri", 
            featureNS: "http://www.openplans.org/topp",
            geometryName: "bounds" 
        })
    });
```

source: http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/SettingZoomLevels

Answer (score 1):

You Can Use minScale and maxScale within each vector layer as below.

```
var options = 
{
    scales: [50000, 100000, 150000],
    projection: "EPSG:900913",
    displayProjection: "EPSG:4326",
    units: 'm'
};
map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', options);

ilceSinir = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("İlçe Sınırı",
{
    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
    minScale:1/150000,
    maxScale:1/100000,
    projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS(
    {
        version: "1.1.0",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs",
        featurePrefix: 'topp',
        featureType: "g_ilce_siniri", 
        featureNS: "http://www.openplans.org/topp",
        geometryName: "bounds" 
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After you have created the map you can use this function to get the scales at different zoomlevels:

```
map.events.register('zoomend', this, function (event) {
   var zLevel = map.getZoom();
   var sc = map.getScale();
   document.getElementById('MatrikelOutput').innerHTML = "Level: " + zLevel + " Scale: " + sc;     
});
```

The result could be: "Level 11 Scale 2000". Choose your start and stop zoomlevels and then set them in the layer options:

```
    minScale: 1/10000,
    maxScale: 1/2000
```

Remark that the scale is defined by 1 divided by the scale returned by map.getScale()